# Getting EPSG code from non conventionnal grid

Tags: coordinate-system, epsg

I have a non usual grid defined by `'+proj=stere +lat_0=90. +lon_0=0. +lat_ts=45. +x_0=619652.07 +y_0= 5062818.34 +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84'`

Based on this information, I would like to get the associated EPSG code?

Comment: If it is unusual it probably doesn't have an EPSG code - check http://epsg.io

Comment: Rather check the official https://epsg.org.